# Python - Vectorized difference of dates in 1 million row table

Tags: python, pandas, date, numpy

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
Date                    
2018-04-10 21:05:00        
2018-04-10 21:05:00        
2018-04-10 21:10:00        
2018-04-10 21:15:00     
2018-04-10 21:35:00
```

My goal is to compute the number of rows that are 20 minutes before and 20 minutes after each time (including rows with the same time both before and after). Something like the following:

```
Date                   nr_20_min_bef    nr_20_min_after   
2018-04-10 21:05:00          2                 4                                 
2018-04-10 21:05:00          2                 4  
2018-04-10 21:10:00          3                 2
2018-04-10 21:15:00          4                 2
2018-04-10 21:35:00          2                 1
```

I have tried to perform a for loop to iterate over all rows, the problem is that the whole series has more than million rows, therefore I was looking for a more efficient solution. My current approach is using pandas functions:

```
import datetime
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(['2018-04-10 21:05:00',        
'2018-04-10 21:05:00',        
'2018-04-10 21:10:00',        
'2018-04-10 21:15:00',     
'2018-04-10 21:35:00']),columns = ['Date'])

nr_20_min_bef = []
nr_20_min_after = []

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    nr_20_min_bef.append(df.Date.between(df.Date[i] - 
pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=20), df.Date[i], inclusive = True).sum())
    nr_20_min_after.append(df.Date.between(df.Date[i], df.Date[i] + 
pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=20), inclusive = True).sum())
```

Probably a vectorized solution would be ideal for this case, however, I do not really know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post text, not pictures.  And show the code you have using a for-loop.

Comment: [You should not post code as an image because: ...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Also added the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news is that it is possible to vectorize this. 
The bad news is... it's not exactly simple.

Here is the benchmarking [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

def orig(df):
    nr_20_min_bef = []
    nr_20_min_after = []

    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        nr_20_min_bef.append(df.Date.between(
            df.Date[i] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=20), df.Date[i], inclusive = True).sum())
        nr_20_min_after.append(df.Date.between(
            df.Date[i], df.Date[i] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=20), inclusive = True).sum())
    df['nr_20_min_bef'] = nr_20_min_bef
    df['nr_20_min_after'] = nr_20_min_after
    return df

def alt(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df['num'] = 1
    df = df.set_index('Date')

    dup_count = df.groupby(level=0)['num'].count()
    result = dup_count.rolling('20T', closed='both').sum()
    df['nr_20_min_bef'] = result.astype(int)

    max_date = df.index.max()
    min_date = df.index.min()
    dup_count_reversed = df.groupby((max_date - df.index)[::-1] + min_date)['num'].count()
    result = dup_count_reversed.rolling('20T', closed='both').sum()
    result = pd.Series(result.values[::-1], dup_count.index)
    df['nr_20_min_after'] = result.astype(int)
    df = df.drop('num', axis=1)
    df = df.reset_index()
    return df

def make_df(N):
    dates = (np.array(['2018-04-10'], dtype='M8[m]') 
             + (np.random.randint(10, size=N).cumsum()).astype('<i8').astype('<m8[m]'))
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates})
    return df

def check(df1, df2):
    return df1.equals(df2)

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[orig, alt],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(4,10)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='N',
    equality_check=check)
```

which shows `alt` is signficantly faster than `orig`:
[image]

In addition to benchmarking `orig` and `alt`, `perfplot.show` also checks that
the DataFrames returned by `orig` and `alt` are equal. Given the complexity of `alt`, this at least gives us some assurance that it behaves the same as `orig`.

It's a little difficult to make a perfplot for large N since `orig` starts
taking quite a long time and each benchmark is repeated hundreds of times. So
here is a few spot `%timeit` comparisons for larger `N`:

```
| N     | orig (ms) | alt (ms) |
|-------+-----------+----------|
| 2**10 |      3040 |     9.32 |
| 2**12 |     12600 |     10.8 |
| 2**20 |         ? |      909 |

In [300]: df = make_df(2**10)
In [301]: %timeit orig(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.04 s per loop
In [302]: %timeit alt(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.32 ms per loop
In [303]: df = make_df(2**12)
In [304]: %timeit orig(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 12.6 s per loop
In [305]: %timeit alt(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop
In [306]: df = make_df(2**20)
In [307]: %timeit alt(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 909 ms per loop
```

---

Now what is `alt` doing? Perhaps it is easiest to look at a small example using the `df` you posted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(['2018-04-10 21:05:00',        
                                  '2018-04-10 21:05:00',        
                                  '2018-04-10 21:10:00',        
                                  '2018-04-10 21:15:00',     
                                  '2018-04-10 21:35:00']),columns = ['Date'])
```

The main idea is to use `Series.rolling` to perform a rolling sum. When the
Series has a DatetimeIndex, `Series.rolling` can accept a time frequency for the
window size. So we can calculate rolling sums with variable windows of a fix
time span. The first step is therefore to make the dates a DatetimeIndex:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['num'] = 1
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

Since `df` has duplicate dates, group by the DatetimeIndex values and count the number of duplicates:

```
dup_count = df.groupby(level=0)['num'].count()
# Date
# 2018-04-10 21:05:00    2
# 2018-04-10 21:10:00    1
# 2018-04-10 21:15:00    1
# 2018-04-10 21:35:00    1
# Name: num, dtype: int64
```

Now computing the rolling sum on `dup_count`:

```
result = dup_count.rolling('20T', closed='both').sum()
# Date
# 2018-04-10 21:05:00    2.0
# 2018-04-10 21:10:00    3.0
# 2018-04-10 21:15:00    4.0
# 2018-04-10 21:35:00    2.0
# Name: num, dtype: float64
```

Viola, that's `nr_20_min_bef`. [`20T` specifies the window size](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) to be 20 minutes long. `closed='both'` specifies that each window includes both its left and right endpoints.

Now if only computing `nr_20_min_after` were as simple. In theory, all we need to do is reverse the order of the rows in `dup_count` and compute another rolling sum. Unfortunately, `Series.rolling` demands that the DatetimeIndex is monotonically *increasing*:

```
In [275]: dup_count[::-1].rolling('20T', closed='both').sum()
ValueError: index must be monotonic
```

Since the obvious way is blocked, we take a detour:

```
max_date = df.index.max()
min_date = df.index.min()
dup_count_reversed = df.groupby((max_date - df.index)[::-1] + min_date)['num'].count()
# Date
# 2018-04-10 21:05:00    1
# 2018-04-10 21:25:00    1
# 2018-04-10 21:30:00    1
# 2018-04-10 21:35:00    2
# Name: num, dtype: int64
```

This generates a new pseudo datetime DatetimeIndex to group by:

```
In [288]: (max_date - df.index)[::-1] + min_date
Out[288]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-10 21:05:00', '2018-04-10 21:25:00',
               '2018-04-10 21:30:00', '2018-04-10 21:35:00',
               '2018-04-10 21:35:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

These values may not be in `df.index` -- but that's okay. The only thing we need is that the values are monotonically increasing and that the *difference* between the datetimes
correspond to the differences in `df.index` when reversed.

Now using this reversed dup_count, we can enjoy the big win (in perfomance) by taking the rolling sum:

```
result = dup_count_reversed.rolling('20T', closed='both').sum()
# Date
# 2018-04-10 21:05:00    1.0
# 2018-04-10 21:25:00    2.0
# 2018-04-10 21:30:00    2.0
# 2018-04-10 21:35:00    4.0
# Name: num, dtype: float64
```

`result` has the values we desire for `nr_20_min_after` but in reversed order,
and with the wrong index. Here is how we can correct that:

```
result = pd.Series(result.values[::-1], dup_count.index)
# Date
# 2018-04-10 21:05:00    4.0
# 2018-04-10 21:10:00    2.0
# 2018-04-10 21:15:00    2.0
# 2018-04-10 21:35:00    1.0
# dtype: float64
```

And that's basically all there is to `alt`.

Comment: Thank for your answer! Do you also know a solution to just count the dates if a specific condition is verified in other column? So, to count the number of dates 20 min before and after if a specific string is verified in other column? Therefore, we would have not only the columns nr_20_min_bef and nr_20_min_after, but also nr_20_min_bef_variablex and nr_20_min_after_variablex (which would represent the number of times variablex appeared on the rows less than 30 minutes ago).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the new problem completely. But if you post a new question with all the details (a toy example like the one you provided here is much appreciated) I'd be glad to take a look.

Comment: Just did that. Thank you very much for all your help! Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786484/python-vectorized-conditional-variable-sum-based-on-difference-of-dates-on-1-m

Comment: I am assuming that the solution may be extremely similar to the one presented here. However, I am not really getting there.

Comment: is it possible to adapt this solution when applied to two series of datetime values? By this I mean: instead of calculating the amount of dates 20 min before in that same series, we would calculate the values 20min bef and after with respect to the additional series (and not the current one as we are doing in this case). A simple solution would be to iterate each date on the first series and check how many dates 20 min before and after are on the second series. However, since it is a 1million row table, that is way too time consuming. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `apply` even if it's not a vectorized way, it should be faster than with a `for` loop such as:

```
#first create the timedelta of 20 minutes
dt_20 = pd.Timedelta(minutes=20)
# then apply on the first column
df['nr_20_min_bef'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: df['Date'][((x - dt_20) <= df['Date'] ) 
                                                            & (x >=df['Date'])].count())

df['nr_20_min_after'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: df['Date'][(x <= df['Date'] )& 
                                                              ((x + dt_20) >= df['Date'])].count())
```

After doing some `%timeit`, it seems that using the `between` method is a bit faster than with `mask`, so you can do

```
df['nr_20_min_bef'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: df.Date.between(x - dt_20, 
                                                                 x, inclusive = True).sum())
```

and idem for after.