# Python - Vectorized conditional variable sum based on difference of dates on 1 million row table

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas Dataframe:

```
Date                         Variable
2018-04-10 21:05:00             a
2018-04-10 21:05:00             a
2018-04-10 21:10:00             b
2018-04-10 21:15:00             a
2018-04-10 21:35:00             b
2018-04-10 21:45:00             a
2018-04-10 21:45:00             a
```

My goal is to compute the number of rows containing, say, `'a'` that are 30 minutes before and 30
minutes after each time (including rows with the same time both before and
after, but not including each row that is being analysed). Then do the same for each
`Variable`. So for the `Variable` `a` I'd end up with something like the following:

```
Date                   nr_30_min_bef_a    nr_30_min_after_a   
2018-04-10 21:05:00           1                    2                             
2018-04-10 21:05:00           1                    2
2018-04-10 21:10:00           2                    1
2018-04-10 21:15:00           2                    2
2018-04-10 21:35:00           3                    2
2018-04-10 21:45:00           2                    1
2018-04-10 21:45:00           2                    1
```

I have tried to perform a for loop to iterate over all rows, the problem is that
the whole series has more than million rows, therefore I was looking for a more
efficient solution.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-04-10 21:05:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:05:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:10:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:15:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:35:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:45:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:45:00'],
                   'Variable': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a']})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I modified your question a bit using info from your comment [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775083/python-vectorized-difference-of-dates-in-1-million-row-table/50776287?noredirect=1#comment88576707_50776287). Please check that I haven't changed the intended meaning of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776287/190597),
you could use

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-04-10 21:05:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:05:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:10:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:15:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:35:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:45:00',
                            '2018-04-10 21:45:00'],
                   'Variable': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

freq_table = pd.crosstab(index=df['Date'], columns=df['Variable'])
df_bef = freq_table.rolling('30T', closed='both').sum().astype(int)
is_current = (freq_table != 0).astype(int)
df_bef -= is_current
df_bef.columns = ['nr_30_min_bef_{}'.format(col) for col in df_bef.columns]
result = pd.merge(df, df_bef, left_on='Date', right_index=True)

max_date = df['Date'].max()
min_date = df['Date'].min()
pseudo_dates = (max_date - df['Date'])[::-1] + min_date
freq_table_reversed = pd.crosstab(index=pseudo_dates, columns=df['Variable'])
df_after = freq_table_reversed.rolling('30T', closed='both').sum().astype(int)
df_after = pd.DataFrame(df_after.values[::-1], index=freq_table.index, 
                       columns=df_after.columns)
df_after -= is_current
df_after.columns = ['nr_30_min_after_{}'.format(col) for col in df_after.columns]

result = pd.merge(result, df_after, left_on='Date', right_index=True)
print(result)
```

which prints

```
                 Date Variable  nr_30_min_bef_a  nr_30_min_bef_b  nr_30_min_after_a  nr_30_min_after_b
0 2018-04-10 21:05:00        a                1                0                  2                  2
1 2018-04-10 21:05:00        a                1                0                  2                  2
2 2018-04-10 21:10:00        b                2                0                  1                  1
3 2018-04-10 21:15:00        a                2                1                  2                  1
4 2018-04-10 21:35:00        b                3                1                  2                  0
5 2018-04-10 21:45:00        a                2                1                  1                  0
6 2018-04-10 21:45:00        a                2                1                  1                  0
```

---

The main new idea is to use `pd.crosstab` to generate a frequency table:

```
freq_table = pd.crosstab(index=df['Date'], columns=df['Variable'])
# Variable             a  b
# Date                     
# 2018-04-10 21:05:00  2  0
# 2018-04-10 21:10:00  0  1
# 2018-04-10 21:15:00  1  0
# 2018-04-10 21:35:00  0  1
# 2018-04-10 21:45:00  2  0
```

and then sum the numbers in each rolling window:

```
df_bef = freq_table.rolling('30T', closed='both').sum().astype(int)
```

Since you wish to exclude the current row from the count, `is_current` is subtracted from `df_bef`:

```
is_current = (freq_table != 0).astype(int)
df_bef -= is_current
```

Comment: Thank you. But this method is giving me an error on the after column. For example, if you replace on the variable column the last string a, for string b, and if your run the code for df['Variable'] == 'b', the after column is giving me a -1 number. Shoudn't it give a 0 number (since we are counting the number of b's in a 30 min interval after that time)?

Comment: I added a slightly different method which computes all the "befores" and "afters" for all values in `Variable`. See the edit above.

Comment: If I change `df['Variable'] == 'a'` to `df['Variable'] == 'b'` in the code I posted above, I'm not seeing any `-1`s. Are you seeing a `-1` when using your actual `df`? If so, there might be something special in your real `df` that I am not addressing in the code I posted. In that case, it would be very helpful if you could identify what is different about your real `df` than the toy one I am looking at here. (A runnable example which generates a -1 would be extremely helpful.)

Comment: This new approach worked perfectly. You are an absolute star. Thank you very much.